# Width Percentual Flexbox

Tags: react-native, flexbox

Estou com dificuldade em definir items utilizando Flexbox.

O que preciso fazer é deixar meu `item` em `90%`, atualmente estou fazendo assim, porem não funciona.

```
    <View>
        <ScrollView horizontal>
            <View style={Card}>
                <View style={CardItem}>

                </View>
            </View> 
        </ScrollView>
    </View>


const styles = {
    Card: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 80,
        padding: 10
    },
    CardItem: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        width: '90%',
        height: 100
    }
}
```

So funciona caso eu defina meu `width` com valores sem o `%`

Answer (score 0):

Rafael, tente usar o [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html) para capturar o tamanho do dispositivo, crie uma regra de três que receba um valor e faça disso um helper. Eu costumo usar isso pois as interfaces precisam ser exatamente conforme as proporções dos layouts.

Segue o que eu uso:

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

/**
 * SIZES
 * @type {Number}
 */

export const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
export const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;
```